# Optimal path from a list of points c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, path, euclidean-distance

i have this request:
i have a list of points and for each of these i have X, Y coordinate.

my goal is to find the optimal path between these points (I have to use all the points).
for example:

A (xa, ya), B (xb, yb), C (xc, yc), D (xd, yd), E (x, y)
 I use the calculation of the Euclidean distance between two points

My optimal path is for example: D, E, A, C, B

How can i make this?

Answer (score 3):

You are describing an [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) problem which is known as the [**Traveling Salesman Problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

There is **no known polynomial solution** to this problem, but there are some heuristics to it, that are running in polynomial time, but are not guaranteed to find the optimal path.

If you want optimal - a [**brute force search**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) might be needed.

Comment: It's worth pointing out as well that while TSP is NP-hard, and thus probably impossible to guarantee that an optimal solution is found, it is also one of the easier NP-hard problems to solve very well in practice. There are good heuristics (google "iterated lin-kernighan", for example) that can usually find solutions within a percent or so of optimality very quickly, even with tens of thousands of points.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed NP-Hard, but for the special case where you have points in Euclidean space and you use a Euclidean metric to measure distance, there are polynomial time approximation schemes that can get arbitrarily close to the optimal solution.  Check out [this](http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Frederic.Havet/Cours/p753-arora.pdf) paper (a relatively famous approximation algorithm for Euclidean Traveling Salesman Problem).